# Border with text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, borders

please help to me to make a border with text for my images.  I have attached a picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling with? What research have you done on this task?

Answer (score 5):

Use the rectangle tool (with a stroke and no fill) to create a little box over the image:

Rasterize the layer (*Right click on the layer → Rasterize*)

Add some text on a new layer

Now use the *Rectangular Marquee Tool* (<kbd>M</kbd>) to select and cut out an area from the bottom of the rectangle (a little larger then your text)

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Just for fun, some other variations:

[image]

---

If all of your images are the same size, you can create the whole border and merge it into one layer, then just copy the whole layer and paste it on top of every image.

Comment: @WELZ WOULD IT BE POSSIBLE TO KEEP THIS BORDER AS A TEMPLATE SO IT IS UNIFORM ON ALL MY IMAGES?

Comment: @kaur it appears you have accidentally created multiple accounts. You can go to our [help section](/help/merging-accounts) and contact SE to have your accounts merged. Also (again) please don't use ALL-CAPS (which comes across as shouting)